# Error from server (NotFound): pods "\nmongo-client-79667cc85d-tsg72" not found

Tags: bash, kubernetes, kubectl

I'm trying to make a backup from Mongo / K8S with this script

```
export POD=$(kubectl get pods -l app=mongo-client -o custom-columns=:metadata.name -n espace-client)
kubectl exec "$POD" sh -c 'mongodump --archive' > ~/backup/mongo/$(date +%F).db.dump
```

I get this error:

```
Error from server (NotFound): pods "\nmongo-client-79667cc85d-tsg72" not found
```

When I check the pods, I can see `mongo-client-79667cc85d-tsg72`

When I put the name without variable, it works well, so it might be because of initial `\n`. How can I avoid it ?
How can I remove it from name ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The output of your `kubectl get pods` command has a newline before the pod name because the first line of the output is the column header (which is empty in your case).

To prevent this and get only the name as output, you can suppress the column headers with the `--no-headers` flag:

```
kubectl get pods -l app=mongo-client -o custom-columns=:metadata.name -n espace-client --no-headers
```

Answer (score 7):

Your `kubectl get pods` command is constrained with a namespace selector `-n espace-client`.  Your `kubectl exec` command also needs the namespace flag.

Comment: This was my issue

Comment: Why wen I do this command `do kubectl port-forward $(kubectl get pods --all-namespaces --no-headers -o custom-columns=":metadata.name" | grep $1) $2:$2` I also need to set namespace for `kubectl port-forward`?

Comment: Because the command within the `$(...)` returns only pod names.  A pod is a namespaces resource, meaning you must specify in which namespace it is located in order to create the port forward.